# onMouseover custom dictionary that automatically parses contents applies tooltips?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, coffeescript

I have a website that uses terms which are not "common" and sometimes require clarification.  I have considered creating a JavsScript solution that will read terms from a dictionary file, parse each page and then apply highlighting and an `onMouseover` tooltip for users to easily read term definitions.

***Is there a library that already exists to accomplish this?***  I've seen a few things that are half baked options, but nothing is very clean and comprehensive in this regard to what I'm looking for.

To give an example scenario, I'd like for the solution to function similarly:  I would provide a data / definition file something like:

```
"some term 1", "the definition will be explained over here in verbose terms"
"some term 2", "the definition will be explained over here in verbose terms"
"some term 3", "the definition will be explained over here in verbose terms"
```

Then the JavaScript, on page load, would parse this definition file.  It would then parse the contents of the dom and isolate each term (`some term 1`,`some term 2`, `etc.`), populating the term's tooltip with the appropriate definition text.  Obviously the elegance of this is that it only ever requires updating the definition file and all of the site content will have a handy dictionary in place for the reader.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I would use jQuery UI for this...

http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

As far as the dictionary part, I would create a script that loads on each page and looks for the existence of specific words and checks them against a JSON file.
Do you want code? Or is concept good enough?

Comment: Yes, you're thinking along the same lines as initially I thought, however I'm not real keen with js at the moment and would really love to see some js or CoffeeScript example.  CoffeeScript would be the shiz as I'm moving in that direction.

Comment: Gotcha... I'll write a simple code for parsing the JSON file when I get a chance. JSON is the easiest data to read and write.

Comment: Really looking forward to your input in this regard.

Comment: I'll have something for you tomorrow night. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/) and add the `clarification` to the element `title`.
It's a `tooltip` which is displayed on `hover`.

Comment: Yes, Tipsy certainly seems like an option, but what about the first part with regards to providing the definition file that will give term keys and definitions to dynamically populate the tooltip?